# ElasticSearch how to setup geo_point

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to setup a geo_point object on ES 1.0.0 and run a simple proof of concept query against it but the query is failing to return any hits.  Here are my setup steps:

1) Create the mapping:

```
PUT jay/geotest/_mapping
{
    "geotest" : {
        "properties" : {
            "name" : {
                "type" : "string"
            },
            "pin" : {
                "type": "geo_point"   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2) verify the mapping:

```
GET jay/geotest/_mapping
```

3) Add a piece of data

```
put jay/geotest/1
{
   "name": "test1",
   "pin": {
      "lat": 0,
      "lon": 0
   }
}
```

4) query for that data:

```
GET jay/geotest/_search?search_type=count
{
    "filtered" : {
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "100km",
                "pin" : {
                    "lat" : 0,
                    "lon" : 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My expected result is that I will get one hit returned but instead nothing is returned by the query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems you are working off of this: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html. Is there a reason you left off the query portion (match_all)?

Comment: the "match_all" is implicit and therefore not required with ES.  I did try adding it just to double check and I'm still getting no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the "query" part of the request.

```
POST jay/geotest/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "geo_distance": {
               "distance": "100km",
               "pin": {
                  "lat": 0,
                  "lon": 0
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I've just tested your steps, and making that change returns the document.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks Akshay!